# Accessing webserver inside WSL from Windows(chrome)

Tags: docker, kubectl, wsl-2

I'm using WSL(v2) and have a web server running inside it.

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                 STATUS   ROLES           AGE     VERSION
kind-control-plane   Ready    control-plane   3d21h   v1.25.0
```

And I can ping my "website" from within WSL [ping mysite.com] just fine

On my Windows side, I have Docker Desktop running.
Under Containers:

```
NAME                IMAGE                STATUS   PORTS
kind-control-plane  kindest/node:<none>  Running  443,42725,80
```

I have also enabled all [WSL] related options under Docker Desktop -> Settings

I want to access this website in Chrome and tried:

```
localhost:443 = err 400
localhost:42725 = Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server. With https, err 403
localhost:80 = err 404
```

I also tried adding the port 42725 to my firewall allowed list but nothing seems to change.

I searched and found multiple Q&As pointing me here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking 
I tried these:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=80listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=80connectaddress={hostname -I}
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=443listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=443connectaddress={hostname -I}
```

but nothing changes. 
However, when I do this

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=42725listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=42725connectaddress={hostname -I}
```

And then try to restart:

```
$ docker start kind-control-plane
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 127.0.0.1:42725 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:42725: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
Error: failed to start containers: kind-control-plane
```

I also tried a completely different [listenport] but it didn't work either.

I'm actually not sure what ports to put inside the listenport/connectport options. Also, should I change listenaddress=0.0.0.0 to something else?
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly you able to access webserver physically (because error status codes like 400, 403, 404 returning by webserver). So the problem is why webserver returning 40X instead of 200. And this problem depends on what server is used, what auth logic is implemented, what security settings set, how do you tried to use https certificate with local IP address, etc, etc, etc

Comment: I'm really new at this, so I tried: [kind create cluster --name helloworld]. [kind get nodes] shows only my original kind-control-plane, but my DockerDesktop shows [helloworld-control-plane]. Anyway, I tried to connect to it using my Browser and it has the same issues. "Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server". The [netsh interface portproxy add] command doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: I also tried "Test-NetConnection" to ping each port, 443 and 80 works, but 42725 fails. The helloworld port fails as well.

Comment: Can you run this command<netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=<your ip address> > and try connecting again

Comment: I got it to work by adding my site to the windows hosts file:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal mysite.com

Comment: Can you post the solution steps you have followed and accept it for better community reach